# What happens after onClick is finished. Android

Tags: java, android

In my app after they press an on screen button. In the listener I do some check to see if they win. When they win i set a boolean like so:

```
 button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       /** check some things **/
       aWin = true;
    }
 }
```

I am wondering. Where does the code go after the onClick. Am i suppose to call the function in the onClick?

I have looked everywhere for an answer, I am very new to android programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "the function" you mean a funcion that you have developed, then Yes, you should call whatever function you want to execute in the onClick method.

For example:

```
button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view)
  {
   /** check some things **/
   aWin = true;
   //Example
   this.informUser(aWin) //Call your function here
   }
 }
```

If by "the funcion" you mean the onClick, then no, you shouldn't call it, Android OS should do it for you.

Comment: I had done what you posted in your answer. `resetScreen()` which calls three other functions. When it completed the the first function, my app crashed with the error `performing stop of activity that is not resumed`

Comment: Try commenting all the calls inside resetScreen(), and make it do something simple like showing a Toast, so that you make sure that you are calling the function correctly. Then you can work on the errors, or post another question for that errors in particular

Answer (score 0):

> Where does the code go after the onClick. Am i suppose to call the
>   function in the onClick?

It depends on what you do in the `onClick`.

For example :

```
button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       /** check some things **/
       aWin = true;
    }
 }
```

In your code above, the code will stop at aWin = true;.

Now lets say you want to go to another `Activity` after a click happened :

```
button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       /** check some things **/
       Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
    }
 }
```

The `onClick` will end when your apps go to another `activity`.

**UPDATE**

Lets say you want to "refresh" your `TextView` after a click happened :

```
button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       /** check some things **/
       aWin = true;
       if(aWin)
          myText.setText("WIN");
       else
          myText.setText("LOSE");

    }
 }
```

Feel free to comment if you still have some questions (although no guarantee i can answer it) :)

Comment: I want to refresh my view. Clear the screen and redisplay items.

Comment: @AlexClark what kind of view? a list view? a text view? Please see my updated code

Comment: View being the phone screen so my main activity layout. I only have one activity.

Comment: @AlexClark please see my updated answer. A layout may have a lot of views (text view, image view). It depends on what you want to do with those views. I gave you an example how to change a textview's text

Comment: So one activity -> one layout -> many views. You welcome :) Please accept my answer